# For each loop get td value on click event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, onclick

I have a table in my view page, which display a list of values using foreach as following:

```
 <tr>
                        <td >
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list.First().Project_Name)
 @Html.Hidden("TProjectId", list.First().Project_Id, new { id = "pro" + i })
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => list.First().Task_Name)
@Html.Hidden("TTaskId", list.First().Task_Id, new { id = "Tsk" + i })                        
                        </td>

                        @foreach (var dateitem in list)
                        {
                            if (dateitem.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || dateitem.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                            {
                                <td >
                                    <input id="Day1" name="Day1" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" />                                
                                </td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td id="HoursTxt">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(modelitem => dateitem.Hours, new { id = string.Format("txtHours") }) 
                                    @Html.Hidden("CuDate", dateitem.Date)
                                        <img src="~/Images/comment.png" class="prevtest" />                            
                                    <div style="border:solid;display:none;">
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => dateitem.Notes, new { id = "TxtNotes" })
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            }
              }
                    </tr>
```

I want to get date(hidden field) while clicking on image in this...
My jquery is like following:

```
 $('.prevtest').on('click', function () {
            $(this).next().toggle();       
            var id = $('#CuDate').val(); alert(id);
var ProjId = $(this).closest("tr").find("#TProjectId").text(); alert(ProjId);
    });
```

I got the first date only when I click on any images.
For project id in hidden field how can i get it? currently empty data return
Can anyone help me to do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hidden element is prev sibling of clicked image. thus you can traverse to the element using `.prev()` selector along with clicked element context `this`:

```
$('.prevtest').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();       
    var id = $(this).prev().val(); 
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: HI @Milind thank you now it's working. But, for projetId in hidden field when i trie as mentioned above, it's return empty value. can you give me suggestion

Comment: @KaviSuja: you mean when `$('#CuDate').val()` is used??

Comment: now it's working.. Thank you. I used as follows    'var ProjId = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();'

Answer (score 2):

You need to find previous element of clicked image tag.

```
$('.prevtest').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();       
        var id = $(this).prev('#CuDate').val(); 
        alert(id);
});
```

Comment: thank you its working now. I have another difficulties with this.. When i try to get projectid I use var ProjId = $(this).closest("tr").find("#TProjectId").text(); alert(ProjId); but it return empty value.. could you help me

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#alertData tr td').click(function(){
var cid = $(this).attr('id');
alert(cid);
var cval = $(this).text();
alert(cval);
});
```